# Center scrlayer-scrpage head-text within header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I have used the power of google + copy/paste to get a header with a look I like, solid band of colour + text. However unfortunately the text isn't centered within the band, and I'm not sure how to make it move around (at least from a precursory glance at KOMA-script's documentation). Also while I'd image there's some way I could shift it by a bit, I'd quite like to **centre** it within the header, not just force it to move up by *X* mm.

[image: Header]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\leftmark} % section on the inner (oneside: right) side
% \ohead{\rightmark} % subsection on the outer (oneside: left) side
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries\upshape\color{contrastColour}} % header upshape instead italic
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{primaryColour}}
% \renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{schrift}\normalfont\slshape}

% Defining the Layer
% \makeatletter
\newlength{\topheight}
\setlength{\topheight}{\sls@topmargin}
\addtolength{\topheight}{\headheight}
\DeclareLayer[
    background,
    contents={%
        \color{primaryColour}%
        \rule{\paperwidth}{\topheight}%

    }%
]{scrheadings.head.background}
% \makeatother

%Adding the Layer to the pagestyles
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
    scrheadings.head.background,%
}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{%
scrheadings.head.background}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demo Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your given code is no MWE as it is missing the document class for example. Please make a complete compilable one from it.

Comment: I've updated the MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to shift the layers starting with `scrheadings.head.` and `plain.scrheadings.head.`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries\upshape\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{blue}}

% shift the predefined head layers
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head.}
    {\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.5in-.5\voffset-.5\topmargin]{#1}}
    {}%
}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.head.}
    {\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.5in-.5\voffset-.5\topmargin]{#1}}
    {}%
}

% Defining the Layer
\DeclareLayer[
    background,
    topmargin,
    addheight=\headheight,
    contents={%
        \color{blue!30!black}%
        \rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}%
    }%
]{my.head.background}

%Adding the Layer to the pagestyles
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{my.head.background}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{my.head.background}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Additional remark: If possible, avoid the usage of internal KOMA-Script commands like `\sls@topmargin`.